# Поменять местами первые элементы двумерного массива, с элементом на главной диагонали

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Товарищи, не понимаю как это осуществить. 
Предполагал, что это можно сделать через swap, но что-то пошло не так

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
const int size=10;
int i, j, num=1;
int ar[size][size];
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    for (j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        ar[i][j]=num;
        num++;
    }
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    for (j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        cout<<ar[i][j]<<"\t";
        if (j==size-1) cout<<"\n\n";
    }
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    for (j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (ar[i][0]) swap(ar[i][0],ar[i][j]);
        cout<<ar[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

помогите пожалуйста :(

Comment: В строке `if (ar[i][0]) swap(ar[i][0],ar[i][j]);` никак не фигурирует элемент с главной диагонали. И зачем там `if`?

Comment: @Константин Что такое "первые элементы двумерного массива"?

Comment: Те, что первые в матрице

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=1; i<size; i++) {
    swap(ar[i][0], ar[i][i]);
}
```

Вместо последнего цикла в Вашем коде. Начинаем цикл с 1, т.к. для первой строки первый элемент (индекс 0) - и есть элемент с главной диагонали.